# MATLAB:plotting multiple circles with varying radius specified by a vector

Tags: contour

I have a scatter graph of some rectangular coordinates which are coloured according to Z data. What i want to show on the grid is varying distances away from 0,0 (kind of like contour rings) so I can visually see which points are in a particular band in meters. as I know the distance of each point away from 0,0 I thought maybe I could use linspace to generate say 10 different distance bands and plot them all together.
anyone help me achieve this or know a better way?